# Exporting JSON API result into CSV file (Vertically AND with Header)

Tags: python, json, api, csv

I'm trying to export JSON API result into a CSV with a right format.

Note: SmartMover API can help determine whether an individual address is up to date by inputting individual address, first name, last name, etc.

Below is my API result in a JSON format.

### JSON API result

> {'CASSReportLink': 'https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/Reports/CASSReport.aspx?tkenrpt=YvBDs39g52jKhLJyl5RgHKpuj5HwDMe1pE2lcQrczqRiG3/3y5yMlixj5S7lIvLJpDyAOkD8fE8vDCg56s3UogNuAkdTbS2aqoYF5FvyovUjnXzoQaHaL8TaQbwyCQ2RB7tIlszGy5+LqFnI7Xdr6sjYX93FDkSGei6Omck5OF4=', 'NCOAReportLink': 'https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/Reports/NCOAReport.aspx?tkenrpt=8anQa424W7NYg8ueROFirapuj5HwDMe1pE2lcQrczqRiG3/3y5yMlixj5S7lIvLJpDyAOkD8fE8vDCg56s3UogNuAkdTbS2aqoYF5FvyovUjnXzoQaHaL8TaQbwyCQ2RB7tIlszGy5+LqFnI7Xdr6sjYX93FDkSGei6Omck5OF4=', 'Records': [{'AddressExtras': '', 'AddressKey': '78704,78704', 'AddressLine1': '                                                            ,                                                            ,                                                            ,STE C-100                                                   ', 'AddressLine2': '1009 W MONROE ST                                            ,1600 S 5TH ST                                               ,1008 W MILTON ST                                            ,3939 BEE CAVES RD                                           ', 'AddressTypeCode': '', 'BaseMelissaAddressKey': '', 'CarrierRoute': '', 'City': 'Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ', 'CityAbbreviation': 'Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ', 'CompanyName': '', 'CountryCode': 'US', 'CountryName': 'United States', 'DeliveryIndicator': '', 'DeliveryPointCheckDigit': '', 'DeliveryPointCode': '', 'MelissaAddressKey': '', 'MoveEffectiveDate': '', 'MoveTypeCode': '', 'PostalCode': '78704,78704,78704,78746', 'RecordID': '1', 'Results': 'AE07', 'State': '', 'StateName': 'TX                                                ,TX                                                ,TX                                                ,TX                                                ', 'Urbanization': ''}], 'TotalRecords': '1', 'TransmissionReference': '1353', 'TransmissionResults': '', 'Version': '4.0.4.48'}
>   [Finished in 2.6s]

From this result, I want to extract 4 output values in AddressLine2 header. (I input 4 values into the API)  For example,

> 'Records':..............'AddressLine2': '1009 W MONROE ST', ............

So I wrote the following Python query:

```
r = response.json()

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\users\testu\documents\travis_test.csv",delimiter = ',',na_values="nan")

with open(r'C:\users\testu\documents\travis3.csv', 'w+') as f:
    cf = csv.writer(f)
    cf.writerow(r['Records'][0]['AddressLine2'].split(','))

print(r['Records'][0]['AddressLine2'].split(','))
```

However, it only extracted values without Header AND horizontally as you can see the picture below:

[image]

How can I extract values with a Header (AddressLine2) AND vertically?

THanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do something similar to this recently. I ended up using a different approach though, and didn't use Pandas.

I am assuming that you are using the python requests library, the csv library, pandas, and python 3.

Assuming you are only trying to get the one column with header AddressLine2, then something like this should work:

```
import requests
import unicodedata
import csv

url = "The API endpoint"

# Build an array to contain the Address values. Add the header AddressLine2
# by appending the string to output_1.
output_1 = []
output_1.append("AddressLine2")

# Get the information from the API using requests.
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

# Collect only Address Line 2 from the JSON output. properly encode/decode the 
# string and add it to output_1. 
for record in data['records']:
    addressline2 = record['addressline2']
    decode_1 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', addressline2)
    output_1.append(decode_1)

# Write the values to a column
with open(csvfile, 'w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, dialect = 'excel')
    for val in output_1:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

I realize I didn't use pandas for this. So this might be too much extra work if you need that pandas dataframe for other calculations. If not, though, then this will hopefully get you that column!